# Structure rails association[user -> one review -> single model]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have 3 models user, app and review

Current my models have the following associations

User -> `has_many :reviews`, `has_many :apps`

Review -> `belongs_to :app`, `belongs_to :user`

App -> `has_many :reviews`, `belong_to :user`

This allow user to create multiple reviews on a simple app model

My question: How to structure my models so that user can add only one review in a single app model?
How to ensure that user can not add review to app he/she created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When create the a review/before save you should check if the user do not own the app he/she is reviewing

Check rails cast [reputation system](http://railscasts.com/episodes/364-active-record-reputation-system) from scratch

Answer (score 0):

In your case just create a Form Object, that would control validations and creation process. Here you can find an example of form object:
http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom validation in review model.

```
validate :user_cannot_be_creator

def user_cannot_be_creator
  errors.add(:user_id, "You are not permited to review") unless user_id != App.find_by(id: app_id).user_id
end
```

*I supose you have `user_id` foreign_key in app and review model and in review model you have `app_id` foreign_key.*